# Syntax error with nesting dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm super confused and feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I'm getting a syntax error on line 8 (the second `'stat': 'OK'`) and have no idea what is wrong with my syntax. There is no specific error message, I just see "Invalid syntax". when I hover over the string `'OK'`.

```
def test_func():
  return 
  {
      {
        'response': {},
        'stat': 'OK'
      },
      'stat': 'OK'
  }
```

Comment: You are missing a key for the first entry in your dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Your nested dictionary is just a value; it needs a key for the outer dict to be valid.

```
def test_func():
  return {
      'your key': {
        'response': {},
        'stat': 'OK'
      },
      'stat': 'OK'
  }
```

The reason you are getting the error on line 8 is that syntax like `{"foo", "bar"}` is valid in Python; it is a set literal. Python only knows that it has invalid syntax when it sees you mixing set literal syntax and dict literal syntax, which happens on line 8 when it sees the first key-value pair.

Edit: Also, you have `return` on a line by itself. This doesn't do what you expect; instead of returning the dict, it returns Python's default return value of `None`. To return the dict, you have to start the dict literal on the same line as `return`.